# How to render a dynamic CSS stylesheet in Vue?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, css-in-js

I'm building an advanced, full-page WYSIWYG tool using Vue. For this, I need to dynamically render a CSS stylesheet based on JSON blobs that contain CSS properties into the `<head>` of a page.

What is the most performant way to do this? Vue uses the concept of scoped CSS, which is compiled at build time. It doesn't allow runtime modification. What I need is the ability to modify, compile and render the CSS at runtime.

**Current solution**

I currently have a regular Vue component, in which I use a reducer to transform the JavaScript into a CSS string, which is rendered inside a `<style>` tag.

However, this entire string gets re-rendered on every single CSS change. This is not performant enough for my use case.

**Desired solution**

A solution that would render my CSS rules without relying on a single Vue component, so that it's picked up by Vue's Virtual DOM and benefits from its performance.

Now that I'm writing this, I think it might be a solution to render a Vue component for every single CSS class, but I'm not sure if that would work. I'm curious to hear other perspectives to this problem.

Comment: What about using custom properties (aka CSS variables)? It's not clear from your question if it's just a single component on your page that needs this WYSIWYG functionality, or does it apply to the entire page (something like a full-page editor). I find your question a little too broad, since you didn't go into specific implemetation details or have a specific problem statement. Can you show us an example of what you're trying to achieve?